# Rename files recursively Linux

Tags: linux

In Linux, I have a folder with files of the following names:

```
Abaraham test.txt 
Jacoobs_resulr.txt
Brabraim's test.txt 
....
Jamine.txt '
```

May I know how could I rename the files recursively to file1.txt ... file20.txt?

Comment: I suggest to use Double Commander as file manager. There is a feature called "bulk rename" it is allow to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any alternative solution using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
cnt=0; for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "file$f$cnt.txt" && cnt=$[cnt + 1]; done
```

Comment: Fixed, was not working because of spaces in cnt = 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Alice. However my file name became: fileAbaraham test.txt1.txt  fileJacoobs_resulr.txt2.txt instead. Is there a way to remove the old name and replace with new name instead (ex: Abraham test.txt -> file1.txt, Jacoobs_resulr.txt -> file2.txt)?

Comment: @KusisiKarem yes, `cnt=0; for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "file$cnt.txt" && cnt=$[cnt + 1]; done`